# How to prove that two lines of a quadrilateral are parallel?

Tags: geometry

7. Given that AC bisects ∠DAB and that AB=BC, prove that AD is parallel to BC.
   I need to know why for each statement (e.g. SSS, ASA, SAS, CPCTC, Isoceles Biconditional)

[image]

Comment: What work have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $<DAC \cong <BAC$, and $<BAC \cong <BCA$ because $AB = BC$.

Answer (score 0):

HInts:

$<DAC=<CAB=<ACB$